# Mule merge two xml response from SOAP services

Tags: xml, soap, mule, mule-studio

I'm have successful get response from multiple services But I don't know how to aggregate responses to final xml

```
[enter image description here][1]
Exception while executing: 
                    id :  customer.id
                                   ^
Type mismatch
     found :name, :string
  required :name, :object (com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException). Message payload is of type: WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhTtK.png)

**Update** this is my  configuration file sory little bit late,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json"
    xmlns:ws="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws" xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata"
    xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:data-mapper="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper"
    xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking"
    xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper/current/mule-data-mapper.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws/current/mule-ws.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd">
    <mulexml:namespace-manager
        includeConfigNamespaces="true">
        <mulexml:namespace prefix="sch"
            uri="http://www.mulesoft.com/schemas/Mule/Schema.xsd" />
        <mulexml:namespace prefix="ds" uri="tsystems.sk/pirates/ds" />
                <mulexml:namespace prefix="soapenv" uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />



        <mulexml:namespace prefix="spl"
            uri="http://www.example.org/split/" />
    </mulexml:namespace-manager>
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
        host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />
    <db:mysql-config name="MySQL_Configuration" host="localhost"
        port="3306" user="root" password="admin" database="bank"
        doc:name="MySQL Configuration" />
    <ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer"
        wsdlLocation="CustomerDS.wsdl" service="CustomerDS" port="SOAP11Endpoint"
        serviceAddress="http://172.27.0.22:8280/services/CustomerDS" doc:name="Web Service Consumer" />
    <ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer1"
        wsdlLocation="Adress.wsdl" service="AddressDS" port="SOAP11Endpoint"
        serviceAddress="http://172.27.0.22:8280/services/AddressDS" doc:name="Web Service Consumer" />
    <db:generic-config name="Generic_Database_Configuration" url="jdbc:postgresql://172.27.0.22:5432/postgres?user=postgres&amp;password=postgres" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" doc:name="Generic Database Configuration"/>
    <flow name="soap-on-db-Flow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
            path="/split" doc:name="ReceiveHttpRequest" />
        <cxf:proxy-service namespace="http://www.example.org/split/" service="split" doc:name="CXF" payload="body" wsdlLocation="split.wsdl"/>
        <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer
            doc:name="DOM to XML" />
        <set-variable variableName="operation"
            value="#[message.inboundProperties.soapaction]" doc:name="Variable" />
        <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="">
                <scatter-gather doc:name="Scatter-Gather">
                    <processor-chain>
                        <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer1" operation="getAllAddresses" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
                        <set-variable variableName="addressList" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Variable"/>
                        <logger message="#[flowVars.addressList]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                    </processor-chain>
                    <processor-chain>
                        <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="getAllCustomers" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
                        <set-variable variableName="customers" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Variable"/>
                        <logger message="#[flowVars.customers]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                    </processor-chain>
                </scatter-gather>
            </when>
            <otherwise >
                <db:select config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
                    <db:dynamic-query><![CDATA[Select * from customer]]></db:dynamic-query>
                </db:select>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="sds"/>



    </flow>
</mule>
```

this is my error all the time I dont know how to handle that

```
INFO  2016-04-07 10:13:53,882 [[soap-mysql-howto_1.0.0-3].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: sds
WARN  2016-04-07 10:13:53,953 [[soap-mysql-howto_1.0.0-3].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Interceptor for {http://www.example.org/split/}split#{http://www.example.org/split/}NewOperation has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not find a transformer to transform "CollectionDataType{type=java.util.LinkedList, itemType=java.lang.Object, mimeType='*/*'}" to "SimpleDataType{type=javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}".
    at org.mule.module.cxf.support.OutputPayloadInterceptor.handleMessage(OutputPayloadInterceptor.java:98) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272) ~[cxf-api-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor.handleMessage(OutgoingChainInterceptor.java:83) ~[cxf-api-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272) ~[cxf-api-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) ~[cxf-api-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfInboundMessageProcessor.sendThroughCxf(CxfInboundMessageProcessor.java:416) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfInboundMessageProcessor.sendToDestination(CxfInboundMessageProcessor.java:290) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfInboundMessageProcessor.process(CxfInboundMessageProcessor.java:155) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.config.FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.process(FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.java:49) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:102) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.construct.DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.process(DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.java:55) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:80) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:76) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.processBlocking(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:58) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:41) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.processBlocking(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:80) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:76) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:50) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:76) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:22) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:66) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:61) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$3.process(AbstractPipeline.java:231) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.routeEvent(HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.java:72) ~[mule-module-http-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase$1.process(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:71) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase$1.process(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:58) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:35) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:22) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:67) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:110) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.runPhase(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:57) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.runPhase(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:34) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.phaseSuccessfully(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:65) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.phaseSuccessfully(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at com.mulesoft.mule.throttling.ThrottlingPhase.runPhase(ThrottlingPhase.java:185) ~[mule-module-throttling-ee-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at com.mulesoft.mule.throttling.ThrottlingPhase.runPhase(ThrottlingPhase.java:1) ~[mule-module-throttling-ee-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.process(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:114) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine.process(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:41) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.execution.MuleMessageProcessingManager.processMessage(MuleMessageProcessingManager.java:32) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.DefaultHttpListener$1.handleRequest(DefaultHttpListener.java:127) ~[mule-module-http-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.java:83) ~[mule-module-http-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.21.jar:2.3.21]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.21.jar:2.3.21]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.21.jar:2.3.21]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.21.jar:2.3.21]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.21.jar:2.3.21]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.21.jar:2.3.21]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.21.jar:2.3.21]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.21.jar:2.3.21]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.run0(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:102) ~[mule-module-http-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.access$100(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:30) ~[mule-module-http-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:125) ~[mule-module-http-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException: Could not find a transformer to transform "CollectionDataType{type=java.util.LinkedList, itemType=java.lang.Object, mimeType='*/*'}" to "SimpleDataType{type=javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}".
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.lookupTransformer(MuleRegistryHelper.java:248) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:418) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:373) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.support.OutputPayloadInterceptor.handleMessage(OutputPayloadInterceptor.java:91) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    ... 109 more
```

Comment: Could you provide your mule config here so we could help better?

Comment: Hi from where are you getting the payload provide full config.Have you tried changing mime type?

Answer (score 0):

Without providing your code it's difficult to answer in more detail but you should consider using the [Scatter-Gather](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/scatter-gather) message processor.

> The Scatter-Gather router sends a message for concurrent processing to
>   all configured routes. The thread executing the flow that owns the
>   router waits until all routes complete or time out.
>
> If there are no failures, Mule aggregates the results from each of the
>   routes into a message collection (MessageCollection class). Failure in
>   one route does not stop the Scatter-Gather from sending messages to
>   its other configured routes, so it is possible that many, or all
>   routes may fail concurrently.

Within your `choice` control you can either embed a `scatter-gather` processor or use a `flow-ref` to call a private flow that holds the logic.

Based on the picture you provided, your `scatter-gather` processor will probably look something like:

```
<scatter-gather doc:name="Scatter-Gather">
    <processor-chain>
        <ws:consumer .../>
        <set-variable .../>
        <logger .../>
    </processor-chain>
    <processor-chain>
        <ws:consumer .../>
        <set-variable .../>
    </processor-chain>
</scatter-gather>
```

You may need to do some further transformations to get your desired output but hopefully this should give you enough to get going.